# JRE virtual machine missing

Tags: java, eclipse

I know that this subject was covered but mine is a little different it seems.
I tried to open Eclipse this morning and didn't work. "A Java Runtime environment(JRE) or Java Development Kit(JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin".

Now in the other questions, it was about \bin\javaw.exe. I verified my Java and I have both JRE and JDK. Why would it not work, it was working perfectly fine two days ago. 
There was Java update on the system, could it be it ?

Comment: Did you upgrade Eclipse recently?  Or your Java installation?  Or did you edit the eclipse.ini file?  Please add the "eclipse.ini" file to your question.

Comment: There was an update for java and I did not do anything else. I am a new to this and so I don't know how to edit the eclipse.ini file. What is it?

Comment: @dtrembl5 The "eclipse.ini" file is in the root directory of your eclipse installation. It may contain a setting for the VM: One line specifying `-vm` and the next line specifying the VM. I suggest to place the path to the file "jvm.dll" there: `${path-to-jdk}/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll`. If it does not contain that setting, you could either add it, or - if you don't want it - check your environment variables, especially `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`. There might be a misconfiguration.

Comment: -vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/

Comment: changed -vm for the new path suggested but it didn't work, I will put it back where it was at first. I will check the JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what might be a temporary solution, now the desktop laucher still doesn't work but I went into the Eclipse root file and found in plugins a launcher : "org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642". 
I was able to open Eclipse and it works for now. Is this the older version launcher ?

Edited: I found a permanent solution. As per suggested in the last comment, the PATH was the problem. I found out the eclipse.ini had jre instead of jdk. So I changed the PATH after the -vm to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\bin.

Now it works! Thank you guys for pointing out the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you downloaded the JDK and JRE which conflicted when you downloaded the update. Your answer is correct however, might I suggest you only use one of the following ? Depending on your use of Eclipse you might want to use more JRE than JDK or the other way around.

This problem will now be avoided if you are using other programming software in the future.